# Show nodes without numbering

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a code that creates XML nodes like so

```
foreach(var books in booksCollection)
            {
                XmlText bookTitle = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(books.bookTitle);
                bookTitle.AppendChild(bookTitle);

                XmlText companyTitle = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(books.companyTitle);
                CompanyTitle.AppendChild(companyName);

                XmlText author = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(books.author);
                Author.AppendChild(author);
            }
```

I'm using a list as there's a lot of data.
Now using "position()" in the XSLT i'm able to print out data based on the list count.
I.E. If there's 3 item it will print out 3 items,like so:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="bookInfo" >  // my code
                <xsl:number value="position()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="bookTitle" /><br/>
                <xsl:value-of select="companyTitle" /> <br/>
                <xsl:value-of select="author" /><br/>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

Problem is the output for using "position()" is it has numbering on it which i do not want.
How do i print out a list without numbering?Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

```
1a_bookTitle   //--> a_bookTitle instead of 1a_bookTitle
a_companyTitle
an_author

2b_bookTitle //--> b_bookTitle instead of 2b_bookTitle
b_companyTitle
ban_author

3c_bookTitle  //--> c_bookTitle instead of 3c_bookTitle
c_companyTitle
can_author
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, just remove this line

```
 <xsl:number value="position()"/>
```

The **xsl:number** will simply output the number, but doesn't control what elements are selected.